# Is there a way to add more elements to a map in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add symptoms to the diseases in Python maps but I'm not able to add symptoms as it is giving an error. Is there a way to do it and also how do I take the input and then calculate the closest disease by using the symptoms that is input by the user?

This is the code:

```
diseases = {'Coronavirus':'fever', 'dry cough','tiredness',
'Common Cold': 'cough', 'cold',
'Heart Attack': 'pain', 'pressure', 'squeezing'}

symptoms = input("Please type your symptoms (If there are multiple then separate them by a ',') (Note: type all in small letters): ")

if symptoms == 'fever, dry cough, tiredness':
    print("Your disease is Coronavirus or cornavirus! Deadly Disease: Yes")

if symptoms == 'cough, cold':
    print("Your disease is Common cold, Deadly Disease: No, but must consult a doctor if sever.")
```

Comment: Using a list, as the below answer by @Devkumar kp is the ideal way to go about it but your `str` comparisons will not work and you're not using your diseases dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it as list

```
diseases = {'Coronavirus':['fever', 'dry cough','tiredness'],
            'Common Cold':['cough', 'cold'],
            'Heart Attack':['pain', 'pressure', 'squeezing']}
```

Comment: That is a good start, but the str comparison later will not work.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but is there a way to take the closest symptoms and the tell the disease?

Answer (score -1):

This is a dictionary, add multiple 'symptoms' (after the :) as a list, so between [..]. Use the following code:

```
diseases = {'Coronavirus': ['fever', 'dry cough','tiredness'], 'Common Cold': ['cough', 'cold'], 'Heart Attack': ['pain', 'pressure', 'squeezing']}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.